# VHDL - Register File Data Does Not Always Write

Tags: vhdl, cpu-registers, xilinx

We are building a processor for our final project. We were told to build the register file with two read outputs and a single write input. We should use muxes to select the registers being read and a decoder to select the register being written.

We are using Vivado 2015.4 and the Nexys4 board. I have synthesized the registers file as part of the whole processor, but not on it's own. I have run a testbench simulation on the registers alone.

Register file top level:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
library work;
use work.RegPackage.all;

entity register_file1 is
    Port ( clk : in STD_LOGIC;
           reset : in STD_LOGIC;
           w_en : in STD_LOGIC;
           w_data : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (63 downto 0);
           r_data1 : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (63 downto 0);
           r_data2 : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (63 downto 0);
           w_reg : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (4 downto 0);
           r_reg1 : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (4 downto 0);
           r_reg2 : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (4 downto 0);
           r_data19 : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (63 downto 0); --Here down are just to track that the registers are being written to properly
           r_data20 : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (63 downto 0);
           r_data21 : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (63 downto 0);
           r_data24 : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (63 downto 0));
end register_file1;

architecture Behavioral of register_file1 is
    signal reg_sel : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);
    signal w_sel: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0);
    signal reg_data0 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(63 downto 0);
    signal reg_data1 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(63 downto 0);
    signal reg_data2 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(63 downto 0);    
    signal reg_data3 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(63 downto 0);
    signal reg_data4 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(63 downto 0);
    signal reg_data5 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(63 downto 0);
    signal reg_data6 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(63 downto 0);
    signal reg_data7 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(63 downto 0);
    signal reg_data8 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(63 downto 0);    
    signal reg_data9 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(63 downto 0);
    signal reg_data10 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(63 downto 0);
    signal reg_data11 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(63 downto 0);
    signal reg_data12 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(63 downto 0);
    signal reg_data13 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(63 downto 0);
    signal reg_data14 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(63 downto 0);    
    signal reg_data15 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(63 downto 0);
    signal reg_data16 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(63 downto 0);
    signal reg_data17 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(63 downto 0);
    signal reg_data18 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(63 downto 0);
    signal reg_data19 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(63 downto 0);
    signal reg_data20 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(63 downto 0);    
    signal reg_data21 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(63 downto 0);
    signal reg_data22 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(63 downto 0);
    signal reg_data23 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(63 downto 0);    
    signal reg_data24 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(63 downto 0);
    signal reg_data25 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(63 downto 0);
    signal reg_data26 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(63 downto 0);
    signal reg_data27 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(63 downto 0);
    signal reg_data28 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(63 downto 0);    
    signal reg_data29 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(63 downto 0);
    signal reg_data30 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(63 downto 0);
    signal reg_data31 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(63 downto 0) := x"0000000000000000"; --zero register

 begin
    --These are signals for the test bench to track if they are being properly written to
    r_data19 <= reg_data19;
    r_data20 <= reg_data20;
    r_data21 <= reg_data21;
    r_data24 <= reg_data24;

    --mux for read data1
    r_data1 <= reg_data0 when (r_reg1 = "00000")
               else reg_data1 when (r_reg1 = "00001")
               else reg_data2 when (r_reg1 = "00010")
               else reg_data3 when (r_reg1 = "00011")
               else reg_data4 when (r_reg1 = "00100")
               else reg_data5 when (r_reg1 = "00101")
               else reg_data6 when (r_reg1 = "00110")
               else reg_data7 when (r_reg1 = "00111")
               else reg_data8 when (r_reg1 = "01000")
               else reg_data9 when (r_reg1 = "01001")
               else reg_data10 when (r_reg1 = "01010")
               else reg_data11 when (r_reg1 = "01011")
               else reg_data12 when (r_reg1 = "01100")
               else reg_data13 when (r_reg1 = "01101")
               else reg_data14 when (r_reg1 = "01110")
               else reg_data15 when (r_reg1 = "01111")
               else reg_data16 when (r_reg1 = "10000")
               else reg_data17 when (r_reg1 = "10001")
               else reg_data18 when (r_reg1 = "10010")
               else reg_data19 when (r_reg1 = "10011")
               else reg_data20 when (r_reg1 = "10100")
               else reg_data21 when (r_reg1 = "10101")
               else reg_data22 when (r_reg1 = "10110")
               else reg_data23 when (r_reg1 = "10111")
               else reg_data24 when (r_reg1 = "11000")
               else reg_data25 when (r_reg1 = "11001")
               else reg_data26 when (r_reg1 = "11010")
               else reg_data27 when (r_reg1 = "11011")
               else reg_data28 when (r_reg1 = "11100")
               else reg_data29 when (r_reg1 = "11101")
               else reg_data30 when (r_reg1 = "11110")
               else reg_data31 when (r_reg1 = "11111");

    --mux for read data 2
    r_data2 <= reg_data0 when (r_reg2 = "00000")
               else reg_data1 when (r_reg2 = "00001")
               else reg_data2 when (r_reg2 = "00010")
               else reg_data3 when (r_reg2 = "00011")
               else reg_data4 when (r_reg2 = "00100")
               else reg_data5 when (r_reg2 = "00101")
               else reg_data6 when (r_reg2 = "00110")
               else reg_data7 when (r_reg2 = "00111")
               else reg_data8 when (r_reg2 = "01000")
               else reg_data9 when (r_reg2 = "01001")
               else reg_data10 when (r_reg2 = "01010")
               else reg_data11 when (r_reg2 = "01011")
               else reg_data12 when (r_reg2 = "01100")
               else reg_data13 when (r_reg2 = "01101")
               else reg_data14 when (r_reg2 = "01110")
               else reg_data15 when (r_reg2 = "01111")
               else reg_data16 when (r_reg2 = "10000")
               else reg_data17 when (r_reg2 = "10001")
               else reg_data18 when (r_reg2 = "10010")
               else reg_data19 when (r_reg2 = "10011")
               else reg_data20 when (r_reg2 = "10100")
               else reg_data21 when (r_reg2 = "10101")
               else reg_data22 when (r_reg2 = "10110")
               else reg_data23 when (r_reg2 = "10111")
               else reg_data24 when (r_reg2 = "11000")
               else reg_data25 when (r_reg2 = "11001")
               else reg_data26 when (r_reg2 = "11010")
               else reg_data27 when (r_reg2 = "11011")
               else reg_data28 when (r_reg2 = "11100")
               else reg_data29 when (r_reg2 = "11101")
               else reg_data30 when (r_reg2 = "11110")
               else reg_data31 when (r_reg2 = "11111");


    decoder1 : decoder port map(reg_addr => w_reg, w => w_en, found => reg_sel);

    --write select signal. Takes the write enable (w_en) and the selected register from the decoder and uses that to determine which, if any, register is to be written to. Register 31 is never selected, because it is the zero register and cannot be written to.
    w_sel(0) <= (reg_sel(0) and w_en);
    w_sel(1) <= (reg_sel(1) and w_en);
    w_sel(2) <= (reg_sel(2) and w_en);
    w_sel(3) <= (reg_sel(3) and w_en);
    w_sel(4) <= (reg_sel(4) and w_en);
    w_sel(5) <= (reg_sel(5) and w_en);
    w_sel(6) <= (reg_sel(6) and w_en);
    w_sel(7) <= (reg_sel(7) and w_en);
    w_sel(8) <= (reg_sel(8) and w_en);
    w_sel(9) <= (reg_sel(9) and w_en);
    w_sel(10) <= (reg_sel(10) and w_en);
    w_sel(11) <= (reg_sel(11) and w_en);
    w_sel(12) <= (reg_sel(12) and w_en);
    w_sel(13) <= (reg_sel(13) and w_en);
    w_sel(14) <= (reg_sel(14) and w_en);
    w_sel(15) <= (reg_sel(15) and w_en);
    w_sel(16) <= (reg_sel(16) and w_en);
    w_sel(17) <= (reg_sel(17) and w_en);
    w_sel(18) <= (reg_sel(18) and w_en);
    w_sel(19) <= (reg_sel(19) and w_en);
    w_sel(20) <= (reg_sel(20) and w_en);
    w_sel(21) <= (reg_sel(21) and w_en);
    w_sel(22) <= (reg_sel(22) and w_en);
    w_sel(23) <= (reg_sel(23) and w_en);
    w_sel(24) <= (reg_sel(24) and w_en);
    w_sel(25) <= (reg_sel(25) and w_en);
    w_sel(26) <= (reg_sel(26) and w_en);
    w_sel(27) <= (reg_sel(27) and w_en);
    w_sel(28) <= (reg_sel(28) and w_en);
    w_sel(29) <= (reg_sel(29) and w_en);
    w_sel(30) <= (reg_sel(30) and w_en);

    --Registers. I know that there is a way to generate these simpler with indexing, but we couldn't get it to work.
    register0 : newRegister port map( clk => clk, reset => reset, w_en => w_en, w_data => w_data , r_data => reg_data0, sel => w_sel(0));
    register1 : newRegister port map( clk => clk, reset => reset, w_en => w_en, w_data => w_data , r_data => reg_data1, sel => w_sel(1));
    register2 : newRegister port map( clk => clk, reset => reset, w_en => w_en, w_data => w_data , r_data => reg_data2, sel => w_sel(2));
    register3 : newRegister port map( clk => clk, reset => reset, w_en => w_en, w_data => w_data , r_data => reg_data3, sel => w_sel(3));
    register4 : newRegister port map( clk => clk, reset => reset, w_en => w_en, w_data => w_data , r_data => reg_data4, sel => w_sel(4));
    register5 : newRegister port map( clk => clk, reset => reset, w_en => w_en, w_data => w_data , r_data => reg_data5, sel => w_sel(5));
    register6 : newRegister port map( clk => clk, reset => reset, w_en => w_en, w_data => w_data , r_data => reg_data6, sel => w_sel(6));
    register7 : newRegister port map( clk => clk, reset => reset, w_en => w_en, w_data => w_data , r_data => reg_data7, sel => w_sel(7));
    register8 : newRegister port map( clk => clk, reset => reset, w_en => w_en, w_data => w_data , r_data => reg_data8, sel => w_sel(8));
    register9 : newRegister port map( clk => clk, reset => reset, w_en => w_en, w_data => w_data , r_data => reg_data9, sel => w_sel(9));
    register10 : newRegister port map( clk => clk, reset => reset, w_en => w_en, w_data => w_data , r_data => reg_data10, sel => w_sel(10));
    register11 : newRegister port map( clk => clk, reset => reset, w_en => w_en, w_data => w_data , r_data => reg_data11, sel => w_sel(11));
    register12 : newRegister port map( clk => clk, reset => reset, w_en => w_en, w_data => w_data , r_data => reg_data12, sel => w_sel(12));
    register13 : newRegister port map( clk => clk, reset => reset, w_en => w_en, w_data => w_data , r_data => reg_data13, sel => w_sel(13));
    register14 : newRegister port map( clk => clk, reset => reset, w_en => w_en, w_data => w_data , r_data => reg_data14, sel => w_sel(14));
    register15 : newRegister port map( clk => clk, reset => reset, w_en => w_en, w_data => w_data , r_data => reg_data15, sel => w_sel(15));
    register16 : newRegister port map( clk => clk, reset => reset, w_en => w_en, w_data => w_data , r_data => reg_data16, sel => w_sel(16));
    register17 : newRegister port map( clk => clk, reset => reset, w_en => w_en, w_data => w_data , r_data => reg_data17, sel => w_sel(17));
    register18 : newRegister port map( clk => clk, reset => reset, w_en => w_en, w_data => w_data , r_data => reg_data18, sel => w_sel(18));
    register19 : newRegister port map( clk => clk, reset => reset, w_en => w_en, w_data => w_data , r_data => reg_data19, sel => w_sel(19));
    register20 : newRegister port map( clk => clk, reset => reset, w_en => w_en, w_data => w_data , r_data => reg_data20, sel => w_sel(20));
    register21 : newRegister port map( clk => clk, reset => reset, w_en => w_en, w_data => w_data , r_data => reg_data21, sel => w_sel(21));
    register22 : newRegister port map( clk => clk, reset => reset, w_en => w_en, w_data => w_data , r_data => reg_data22, sel => w_sel(22));
    register23 : newRegister port map( clk => clk, reset => reset, w_en => w_en, w_data => w_data , r_data => reg_data23, sel => w_sel(23));
    register24 : newRegister port map( clk => clk, reset => reset, w_en => w_en, w_data => w_data , r_data => reg_data24, sel => w_sel(24));
    register25 : newRegister port map( clk => clk, reset => reset, w_en => w_en, w_data => w_data , r_data => reg_data25, sel => w_sel(25));
    register26 : newRegister port map( clk => clk, reset => reset, w_en => w_en, w_data => w_data , r_data => reg_data26, sel => w_sel(26));
    register27 : newRegister port map( clk => clk, reset => reset, w_en => w_en, w_data => w_data , r_data => reg_data27, sel => w_sel(27));
    register28 : newRegister port map( clk => clk, reset => reset, w_en => w_en, w_data => w_data , r_data => reg_data28, sel => w_sel(28));
    register29 : newRegister port map( clk => clk, reset => reset, w_en => w_en, w_data => w_data , r_data => reg_data29, sel => w_sel(29));
    register30 : newRegister port map( clk => clk, reset => reset, w_en => w_en, w_data => w_data , r_data => reg_data30, sel => w_sel(30));
    register31 : newRegister port map( clk => clk, reset => reset, w_en => '0', w_data => w_data , r_data => reg_data31, sel => '0');

end Behavioral;
```

Decoder:

```
entity decoder is
    Port ( reg_addr : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (4 downto 0);
           w : in std_logic;
           found : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0)
         ) ;
end decoder;

architecture Behavioral of decoder is

begin
    process(reg_addr)
    begin

            case reg_addr is
                when "00000" =>  found <= x"00000001";
                when "00001" =>  found <= x"00000002";
                when "00010" =>  found <= x"00000004";
                when "00011" =>  found <= x"00000008";
                when "00100" =>  found <= x"00000010";
                when "00101" =>  found <= x"00000020";
                when "00110" =>  found <= x"00000040";
                when "00111" =>  found <= x"00000080";
                when "01000" =>  found <= x"00000100";
                when "01001" =>  found <= x"00000200";
                when "01010" =>  found <= x"00000400";
                when "01011" =>  found <= x"00000800";
                when "01100" =>  found <= x"00001000";
                when "01101" =>  found <= x"00002000";
                when "01110" =>  found <= x"00004000";
                when "01111" =>  found <= x"00008000";
                when "10000" =>  found <= x"00010000";
                when "10001" =>  found <= x"00020000";
                when "10010" =>  found <= x"00040000";
                when "10011" =>  found <= x"00080000";
                when "10100" =>  found <= x"00100000";
                when "10101" =>  found <= x"00200000";
                when "10110" =>  found <= x"00400000";
                when "10111" =>  found <= x"00800000";
                when "11000" =>  found <= x"01000000";
                when "11001" =>  found <= x"02000000";
                when "11010" =>  found <= x"04000000";
                when "11011" =>  found <= x"08000000";
                when "11100" =>  found <= x"10000000";
                when "11101" =>  found <= x"20000000";
                when "11110" =>  found <= x"40000000";
                when "11111" =>  found <= x"80000000";
                when others => found <= x"00000000";
            end case;

    end process;

end Behavioral;
```

Registers:

```
entity newRegister is
    Port ( clk : in STD_LOGIC;
           reset : in STD_LOGIC;
           sel : in STD_LOGIC; --register select enable
           w_en : in STD_LOGIC; --write enable
           w_data : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (63 downto 0);
           r_data : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (63 downto 0)
           );
end newRegister;

architecture Behavioral of newRegister is
    signal reg: std_logic_vector(63 downto 0); --internal register storage

begin
    process(clk) --nothing happens if this register isn't selected
    begin
        if reset = '1' then
            reg <= x"0000000000000000";
        end if;
        if rising_edge(clk) then
        if sel='1' then
                reg <= w_data; --load new data into register memory
        end if;

        end if;
    end process;
    r_data <= reg ;
end Behavioral;
```

Package:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

package RegPackage is
    component newRegister is
    Port ( clk : in STD_LOGIC;
           reset : in STD_LOGIC;
           sel : in STD_LOGIC; --register select enable
           w_en : in STD_LOGIC; --write enable
           w_data : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (63 downto 0);
           r_data : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (63 downto 0)
           );
    end component;

    component decoder is
        Port ( reg_addr : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (4 downto 0);
               w : in std_logic;
               found : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0)
             ) ;
    end component;

end RegPackage;
```

The testbench is meant to simulate what will happen in the registers for the following ARMv8 Assembly code:

```
ADDI X24, XZR, #2048    // Address 2048 is stored in X24
ADDI X19, XZR, #10  // X19 = a = 10
ADDI X20, XZR, #5   // X20 = b = 5
ADD X21, X19, X20   // X21 = a + b = 10 + 5 = 15
STUR X21, [X24, #0] // send value X21 to 7 seg display
END
```

and is:

```
entity testbench1 is
--  Port ( );
end testbench1;

architecture Behavioral of testbench1 is
 component register_file1 is 
    Port(   clk : in STD_LOGIC;
            reset : in STD_LOGIC;
            w_en : in STD_LOGIC;
            w_data : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (63 downto 0);
            r_data1 : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (63 downto 0);
            r_data2 : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (63 downto 0);
            w_reg : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (4 downto 0);
            r_reg1 : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (4 downto 0);
            r_reg2 : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (4 downto 0);
            r_data19 : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (63 downto 0);
                       r_data20 : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (63 downto 0);
                       r_data21 : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (63 downto 0);
                       r_data24 : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (63 downto 0));
 end component;

        signal clk : STD_LOGIC := '0';
        signal reset : STD_LOGIC := '0';
        signal w_en : STD_LOGIC := '0';
        signal w_data : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (63 downto 0) := x"ABCDEF0123456789";
        signal r_data1 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (63 downto 0) := x"0000000000000000";
        signal r_data2 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (63 downto 0) := x"0000000000000000";
        signal w_reg : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (4 downto 0) := "00000";
        signal r_reg1 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (4 downto 0) := "00000";
        signal r_reg2 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (4 downto 0) := "00000";
        signal r_data19 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (63 downto 0);
        signal r_data20 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (63 downto 0);
        signal r_data21 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (63 downto 0);
        signal r_data24 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (63 downto 0);

begin 


uut: register_file1 PORT MAP (     
            clk => clk,
            reset => reset,
            w_en  => w_en, 
            w_data => w_data, 
            r_data1 => r_data1,
            r_data2 => r_data2,
            w_reg => w_reg,
            r_reg1 => r_reg1, 
            r_reg2 => r_reg2,
            r_data19 => r_data19,
            r_data20 => r_data20,
            r_data21 => r_data21,
            r_data24 => r_data24);
process
 begin
   wait for 10 ns;        
   clk <= not clk;
   w_en <= '1';
   w_data <= x"0000000000000800";
   w_reg <= "11000";
   wait for 10 ns;           
   clk <= not clk;
   w_en <= '0';
   wait for 10 ns;
   clk <= not clk;
   w_en <= '1';
   w_data <= x"000000000000000A";
   w_reg <= "10011";
   wait for 10ns;
   clk <= not clk;
   w_en <= '0';
   wait for 10ns;
   clk <= not clk;
   w_en <= '1';
   w_data <= x"0000000000000005";
   w_reg <= "10100";
   wait for 10ns;
   clk <= not clk;
   wait for 10ns;
   clk <= not clk;
   w_en <= '0';
   r_reg1 <= "10011";
   r_reg2 <= "10100";
   wait for 10ns;
   clk <= not clk;
   wait for 10ns;
   clk <= not clk;
   w_en <= '1';
   w_data <= x"000000000000000F";
   w_reg <= "10101";
   wait for 10ns;
   clk <= not clk;
   wait for 10ns;
   clk <= not clk;
   w_en <= '0';
   r_reg1 <= "10101";
   r_reg2 <= "11000";
   wait for 10ns;       


   wait;
   end process;

end Behavioral;
```

Which results in the following:
[image: RegisterFileTestBench]

It seems to sometimes write, and sometimes not, and I don't know what the difference is between when it does and when it doesn't. It looks like it always reads okay, though.

There seems to be a one clock cycle delay between when the newly written data can be read, which I was not expecting, but I'm not worried about right now.

Comment: 420 lines isn't a [mcve] (some of those are the missing context clauses). However there's only two registers you both write and read in the testbench (the ones that look like they work as shown by we_n = '1' at the rising edge of clk.).  It's  testbench errors (which also relies on a particular vendor ignoring the requirement for a space between an abstract literal and identifiers for 10ns in half a dozen places).

Comment: You use `sel` but not `w_en` inside your registers (newRegister)? You also have an unused `w` port on your decoder. Neither of these are the problem here, but you should try to clean things up.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know how to minimize this further.

I see what you mean in the testbench. It is writing at the rising edge after w_en is turned on. That also explains the delay I noticed. Thank you.

And I will clean up those ports.

Comment: @whimsey it might help to think of it this way: your register is looking for its `sel` signal (and by extension, your uut is looking for its w_en signal) *at* the rising edge of your clock. So your testbench needs to assert w_en *before* the rising edge of the clock.

Comment: I think Kevin is right, you are setting `w_en` at the same time as the clock edge rises. Well, `w_en` must already be set for it to register somewhere else on clock rising edge. If it's set at the exact same time as the clock rising edge, it's new value will not take until the next clock rising edge. I would also recommend stimulating the `reset` and adding `reset` to the sensitivity list of your `newRegister` component. Also, `reset` is typically used in the same if statement as the clock, either higher priority (asynchronous) than clock or checked during clock rising edge (synchronous).

Comment: One other thing, `generate` is your friend when duplicating multiples of the same item.

Comment: *I don't know how to minimize this further.* – For example by reducing the number of registers from 32 to, say, 4. That would also be a good exercise for learning how to make the code more generic so that it works for any number of registers (or at least, for any power of two).

Answer (score 1):

Nothing to do with your question, just a suggestion to reduce your line count: VHDL is a **high level** programming language. It supports many features that you can find in many more classic programming languages. You can use them to improve your code. Example:

```
-- File RegPackage.vhd
...
subtype word64 is std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);
type word64_array is array(natural range <>) of word64;
...

-- File register_file1.vhd
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
library work;
use work.RegPackage.all;

entity register_file1 is
    Port ( clk : in STD_LOGIC;
           reset : in STD_LOGIC;
           w_en : in STD_LOGIC;
           w_data : in word64;
           r_dataA : out word64_array(1 to 2);
           w_reg : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (4 downto 0);
           r_reg1 : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (4 downto 0);
           r_reg2 : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (4 downto 0);
           r_dataB : out word64_array(19 to 24));
end register_file1;

architecture Behavioral of register_file1 is
    signal reg_sel : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);
    signal w_sel: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0);
    signal reg_data : word64_array(0 to 31);
 begin
    --These are signals for the test bench to track if they are being properly written to
    r_dataA <= reg_data (19 to 24);

    --mux for read dataB(1 to 2)
    r_dataB(1) <= reg_data(to_integer(unsigned(r_reg1)));
    r_dataB(2) <= reg_data(to_integer(unsigned(r_reg2)));

    decoder1 : decoder port map(reg_addr => w_reg, w => w_en, found => reg_sel);

    --write select signal. Takes the write enable (w_en) and the selected register from the decoder and uses that to determine which, if any, register is to be written to. Register 31 is never selected, because it is the zero register and cannot be written to.
    w_sel(30 downto 0) <= reg_sel(30 downto 0) and w_en;

    --Registers. I know that there is a way to generate these simpler with indexing, but we couldn't get it to work.
    g_register: for i in 0 to 31 generate
      register : newRegister port map( clk => clk, reset => reset, w_en => w_en, w_data => w_data , r_data => reg_data(i), sel => w_sel(i));
    end generate g_register;

end Behavioral;
```

Notes:

1. In case the version of VHDL you are using does not yet support `vector and scalar`, replace:

   ```
   w_sel(30 downto 0) <= reg_sel(30 downto 0) and w_en;
   ```

   by:

   ```
   g_w_sel: for i in 0 to 30 generate
     w_sel(i) <= reg_sel(i) and w_en;
   end generate g_w_sel;
   ```

   or by:

   ```
   process(reg_sel, w_en)
   begin
     for i in 30 downto 0 loop
       w_sel(i) <= reg_sel(i) and w_en;
     end loop;
   end process;
   ```

   By the way, are you sure you didn't forget index 31?
2. And in case your logic synthesizer complains about:

   ```
   r_dataB(1) <= reg_data(to_integer(unsigned(r_reg1)));
   r_dataB(2) <= reg_data(to_integer(unsigned(r_reg2)));
   ```

   replace these two lines by:

   ```
   process(reg_data, r_reg1, r_reg2)
   begin
     r_dataB <= (others => (others => '0'));
     for i in 0 to 31 loop
       if to_integer(unsigned(r_reg1)) = i then
         r_dataB(1) <= reg_data(i);
       end if;
       if to_integer(unsigned(r_reg2)) = i then
         r_dataB(2) <= reg_data(i);
       end if;
     end loop;
   end process;
   ```

   and consider upgrading to a more recent version of your synthesizer or buying another one.
3. Using the `STD_LOGIC` and `STD_LOGIC_VECTOR` resolved types when you do not intend multiple drive logic (tree-state buffers...) is a bad idea. You should consider using the `STD_ULOGIC`, `STD_ULOGIC_VECTOR` unresolved types instead. Even if many professionals don't really understand the difference and always use the former types "*because we always did like this*".